How to create an output json file from Foundry Pipeline Builder?
How do you write a json file to a Foundry dataset using Pipeline Builder with a properly formatted json string, a designated name, and exportable through a data connection?
I have tried to create an output dataset in Foundry Pipeline Builder and chose the setting to write it as a json file but it still only writes it as a json string in the dataset. When exporting through a data connection, I can get a json file with a generated name (not the one I want) but it is not formatted like the string in the dataset and it is placed in a generated folder ("spark").
Using code repo, I can produce a json file that is stored in the dataset with a name and the json string format needed, and can export through a data connection. I would like to do the same through Pipeline Builder.
